# How to add libraries to dll project in VS2013?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, kinect, vtk, point-cloud-library

I've got a code in C++ built with some libraries like vtk, fltk, pcl and kinect SDK in Visual Studio 2010. My task is taking this project and integrate it into another C#.NET project with Visual Studio 2013.

I was told to do a new project for the dlls and copy the code I need there to make a wrap. My current problem is that I do not know how to add the references so my code can find the includes for the libraries and compile. I have tried to add the .h and .lib manually but does not work. May you give me any hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what your question is, but try this:
Right click on your project in the solution explorer and go to Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input.
In the *additional dependencies* field, add your .lib file(s).

remember to `#include` the corresponding header files in your source file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is not Linker tab in Configuration Properties, I guess my project has different properties since it is a Dll project.

Comment: Maybe you are looking in solution property pages? You need to right click on your project, not solution.

Comment: Yes, you were right and it worked. I also need to add some bins in Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories. Thank you for the help!